# Aggregation of fields inside nested type field

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-mapping

I want to aggregate `keyword` type field which lies inside a `nested` type field. The mapping for nested field is as below:

```
"Nested_field" : {
    "type" : "nested",
    "properties" : {
        "Keyword_field" : {
            "type" : "keyword"
        }
    }
}
```

And the part of query which I am using to aggregate is as below:

```
"aggregations": {
    "Nested_field": {
        "aggregations": {
            "Keyword_field": {
                "terms": {
                    "field": "Nested_field.Keyword_field"
                }
            }
        },
        "filter": {
            "bool": {}
        }
    },
}
```

But this is not returning correct aggregation. Even though there are `Keyword_field` value existing docs, the query returns 0 buckets. So, there is something wrong in my aggregation query. Can anyone help me to find what's wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you need to provide a nested path in there. This worked in ES 5, but it looks like you're using 6 based on the "aggregations" vs "aggs", so let me know if it doesn't work and I'll scrap this answer. Give this a try:

```
{
    "aggregations": {
        "nested_level": {
            "nested": {
                "path": "Nested_field"
            },
            "aggregations": {
                "keyword_field": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "Nested_field.Keyword_field"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: wow !! it worked ... one question though: Does it take a lot of heap memory to aggregate nested fields?

Comment: I'm not too sure on this one. Nested fields are actually stored as separate documents, and what you're doing by adding a `"nested"` node is telling it how/where to look up those separate documents. I'd imagine it's not too much more memory intensive than just a normal aggregation. I imagine there's an extra step to join the nested documents onto the parent documents so it looks like one big document like the way you indexed it; other than that I don't think there's much overhead added.